# Prevent clearing input after closing bootstrap-datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

when using bootstrap-datepicker with:

```
$('.input-group.date').datepicker({
  language: "de",
  todayBtn: "linked",
  todayHighlight: "true",
  autoclose: true
});
```

it removes the current value (hard coded via HTML) from an `<input value="02.02.2017" type="text">` field after it shows up and the user closes the datepicker by clicking anywhere else in the browser. Is there a way to remove this behaviour? Is it possible to let the current value of the `<input value="02.02.2017" type="text">` unchanged after dismissing the datepicker?

Using the option `forceParse: false` doesn't work.

P.S. The format used by bootstrap-datepicker is the same as I use as value in the `<input>` tags: `dd/MM/yy`.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I just created a [minimal example here](https://jsfiddle.net/7z3Lbnyn/) and it keeps the value after leaving the field (although it formats it). What version of the datepicker library are you using?

Comment: Hey @JoshCrozier I'm using 1.6.4. But I think I found the problem. The value is not set via `value=""`, it is set via jQuery `$("#input").val("")`, my fault in the description. If I set it via `value=""` it is still there. But if I set it via jQuery it is gone. Because it is a modal for editing a list it isn't possible to set it directly via `value=""`, I'm forced to set it via `$("input").val("")` because the modal gets populated by each table entrys "edit" button.

Comment: so what is problem with resetting it the way you are doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget about it.

I used another declaration of `.datepicker({` in my code before which blocked the other usage.

Thanks for all your help and don't use `.datepicker({` at the same selector if it is used before in the code.